# Como acessar o textarea, pegar o seu value e exibi-lo?

Tags: javascript, textarea

Estou tentando criar um bloco de notas, e armazena os dados no LocalStorage, entretanto, não consigo ter acesso ao valor que seria digitado pelo usuario, apenas o que já está entre a tag TextArea. Gostaria de pegar o valor do textarea, quando o usuário digitá-lo, e exibi-lo de alguma forma.

---

```
> HTML

<textarea id="txtar">
o console só consegue me retornar o valor escrito no documento, quando eu preciso ter acesso ao valor digitado no campo do TextArea
</textarea>


>JAVASCRIPT

console.log( 
  document.getElementById('txtar').value
  )
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que pretendes que aconteça e o que está a acontecer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vê se te ajuda, brother.

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("#txtar");
let botao = document.querySelector("#botao");

botao.onclick = function() {
  console.log(textarea.value);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtar">Texto digitado dentro do textarea</textarea>
<br>
<button id="botao">Exibir Texto</button>
```

O que você digita no textarea fica sendo o value (valor) do seu campo. Então, quando você exibe o "textarea.value", você está exibindo o que você digitou no textarea (o valor que seu textarea possui agora é o que você digitou).

Você digitar no campo textarea e capturar o seu valor é o mesmo que se você deixar o **textarea** assim:

```
<textarea>Texto dentro do textarea e que é o seu value</textarea>
```

Se você capturar o value desse textarea acima e exibi-lo, o que será exibido será o texto que está dentro do textarea.

Repare no exemplo que coloquei na resposta que se você só clicar no botão de primeira, será exibido o texto (que se torna o valor) que já vem no textarea. Agora se você apagar aquele texto e digitar outra coisa, será exibido aquilo que você digitou (o novo valor).

Comment: deixa eu ver se entendi, para pegar o valor atualizado do text área, é necessário por exemplo a function que o button chama p/ pegar o valor atualizado correto? porém eu consigo automatizar isso de alguma forma? algum tipo de loop, para ser algo automático

Comment: Na verdade você pega o valor atualizado quando ocorre o evento "onclick". Ou seja, quando você "clica" no botão com o id="botao", então é chamada uma função que exibe, através do console.log, o valor que está no textarea. Eu não entendi a parte do "automatizar". Pode explicar melhor o que aconteceria nessa automatização ?

Comment: sim, então, meio que usar o TimeOut de por exemplo, 1 segundo a 1 segundo p/ ir pegando o txtar.value e ir jogando no LocalStorage, pra ir salvando sozinho. MASSS, pefeito moço, sua explicação ja me fez entender todo o necessario kkkk... muito obg pelo engajamento.

Comment: Dá pra pegar perfeitamente utilizando o setTimeOut ou o setInterval. Mas ai vc teria que fazer conforme a sua necessidade.